# Changing block of code based on CONFIG entries in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration-files, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I had a question about using the CONFIG entries of the .config file used in the Linux kernel. I would like to skip through some part of the code in a function in a file based on whether a certain CONFIG entry is y or not. What is the best way of doing that? I am wondering if an 'if statement' can be used in any way. One workaround which I tried was maintaining two copies of almost the same file, renaming, and changing the makefile entries based on CONFIG, but this method involves quite some code duplication. Was wondering if there is a smarted way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an #ifdef on the CONFIG variable - it's recommended that you put the #ifdef in the .h file, then you could use that to change a flag for your function to reference.

See: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6568